# ¿Como puedo agregar un texto grande en Netbeans sin que me lo muestre en una sola linea y se corte?

Tags: java, netbeans

Quisiera saber que debo hacer para que a la hora de ejecutar el programa no me lo muestres así:
ej:
**"Siempre he deseado que mi equipo sea tan fácil de usar como mi teléfono, ....."**
en este ejemplo  el resto del texto no se muestra sigue en una sola linea

quisiera saber como hago para que se muestre así:

**"Siempre he deseado que mi equipo sea tan fácil de usar como mi teléfono, mi deseo se ha hecho realidad porque ya no puedo encontrar la manera de usar mi teléfono"**

Comment: No entiendo :( ¿Qué es este famoso *texto grande en Netbeans*? Probablemente sería mejor si compartes la porción de tu código pertinente a la pregunta para que podamos entender mejor.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con esto:

```
textArea.setLineWrap(true);
```

Y para hacer un reconocimiento de las palabras completas, usa esto:

```
textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
```

Donde `textArea` es el nombre de tu item.